# Multiple Site-To-Site VPN

Tags: vpn

I'm trying to set a VPN that allows all site: site0-4 to communicate with each other. The site called otherSite should not be in the VPN.

Note that there's a NAT for site 0, 1 and 2 but site 3,4 only have private addressing plans in place.

Here's the topology:
[image]

But I'm not sure how it would work, because I'm still not familiar with the VPN configuration.

To my understanding, if we want to sent a packet from site1 to site3 the VPN would encapsulates the packets in the router of site1 and than de-encapsulate it when it reaches site0, where it will be encapsulated again and sent to site3 and it will be de-encapsulate there for the last time, and it would have reached it destination. And if this how it works, my routing tables in the ISP would only contains the addresses of the routers 'interfaces (that of site0,1,2).

I just need a confirmation whether I've got this right or not. And if not, an explanation would be very appreciated.

Thanks you.

Comment: We need more information in order to help you.   There are several different ways to  accomplish this, depending on the specific equipment and capabilities of the WAN provider.  Please edit your question to include the model(s) of your equipment, along with more details about your WAN provider.

Comment: Are you sure you need a VPN over your WAN?

Comment: oh yes, sorry. I didn't add the "otherSite" site to the topology because I thought it wasn't relevant. But yes, I need a VPN there because there's another site there that doesn't belong to the company's sites.

Comment: For my WAN, well first I should note that I'm using packet tracer, and I have 4 routers in my WAN. The device model is router-pt.

Comment: Packet tracer doesn't always accurately simulate real components.  at a high lever, your idea is OK, but specific devices capabilities may require additional components.  for example, you may need a router at site 0 between the two VPNs.